# onClick Function can work only in loading Web Browser, and can't work totally after loading Web Browser

Tags: javascript, php

When I Click the Submit button with id 'submitPasscode', I want to hide the div tag (with id 'passcodeCard') and want to display the div tag (with id 'loginCard').

After Clicking it, onClick function 'checkPasscode()' is worked, but this function works only when loading web browser. It means that div tag (with id 'passcodeCard') didn't hide, and div tag (with id 'loginCard') didn't display after loading web browser.

I would like to know what is wrong with this code to work onClick Function works well.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="passcodeCard" class="loginDiv" style="margin-top: 10%;" style="display: inline;">
<form id="form" class="form-horizontal" style="padding-top: 5%;">
    <div class="group">
    <input type="text" id="passcode" name="passcode" placeholder="Enter Passcode"/>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Enter Passcode</label>
    <button type="submit" class="button buttonBlue" style="margin-top: 5%;" id="submitPasscode" onclick="checkPasscode()">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<div id="loginCard" class="loginDiv widgetHeight" style="display: none;">
<img class="img-responsive user-logo" src="layouts/v7/resources/Images/hims5.png">
        <div>
        <span class="{if !$ERROR}hide{/if} failureMessage" id="validationMessage">{$MESSAGE}</span>
        <span class="{if !$MAIL_STATUS}hide{/if} successMessage">{$MESSAGE}</span>
        </div>

        <div id="loginFormDiv">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="index.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="module" value="Users"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Login"/>
            <div class="group">
            <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="admin">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <label>Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="password">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
        <button type="submit" class="button buttonBlue">Sign in</button><br>
        <a class="forgotPasswordLink" style="color: #15c;">forgot password?</a>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
</div>
<script>
function checkPasscode(){
        if(document.getElementById("passcode").value == "passcode")
            {
                document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("loginCard").style.display = "";
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you want it to stay hidden even after page refresh?

Comment: Yes, I want it to stay hidden even after page refresh.

Comment: I am not sure how you are authenticating the password other than the hard coded password, but after the check of == passcode then you could create a boolean session variable to be like: $isLogin = true; Then you can check in your if statement if you are currently logged in and if not then hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't completely understand your question, but is this what you wanted. I added some extra features such as making the fields required. Please let me know if this helped:

Here is the code:

```html
<div id="passcodeCard" class="loginDiv" style="margin-top: 10%;" style="display: inline;">
<form id="form" class="form-horizontal" style="padding-top: 5%;">
    <div class="group">
    <input type="password" id="passcode" name="passcode" placeholder="Enter Passcode" required/>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Enter Passcode</label>
    <button type="submit" class="button buttonBlue" style="margin-top: 5%;" id="submitPasscode" onclick="checkPasscode()">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<div id="loginCard" class="loginDiv widgetHeight" style="display: none;">
<img class="img-responsive user-logo" src="layouts/v7/resources/Images/hims5.png">
        <div>
        <span class="{if !$ERROR}hide{/if} failureMessage" id="validationMessage">{$MESSAGE}</span>
        <span class="{if !$MAIL_STATUS}hide{/if} successMessage">{$MESSAGE}</span>
        </div>

        <div id="loginFormDiv">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="index.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="module" value="Users"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Login"/>
            <div class="group">
            <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="admin" required>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <label>Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="password" required>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
        <button type="submit" class="button buttonBlue">Sign in</button><br>
        <a class="forgotPasswordLink" style="color: #15c;">forgot password?</a>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
</div>
<script>
function checkPasscode(){

        if(document.getElementById("passcode").value == "passcode")
            {
                document.getElementById("form").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("loginCard").style.display = "block";
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Tommy, it works well by changing document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none" to document.getElementById("form").innerHTML

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice, Mr. Tommy.